# Android how to animate view according to its height/width

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

Hi I'm trying to use `ObjectAnimator` to translate/scale size of the view in and out of the screen according to its size.

So far I manage to utilize `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` to check the size when it's being populated.

```
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {

    tray_height = menu.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

This work for a static size menu with unwanted side-effect that it get displayed for a split second before I can hide it. However, now I need to animate two objects at once by using one of the view's height.

For example, I have MapView display in full screen. When user touch one of the onscreen button, I'd like to scale MapView to make space for the incoming view. The incoming view then translate into the view to display its content.

I knew that this is possible on tablet because [Trulia for rent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trulia.android) has pretty much the same effect that I wanted to go for. Is there some way to achieve this but with dynamic height instead?